# Undefined index: text_unitcost in C:\wamp\www\cdij\insert.php on line 13

Tags: php, html

I am Trying to Insert a value into a table. But I am getting an error:
 Undefined index: text_unitcost in C:\wamp\www\cdij\insert.php on line 13

Insert page is The page through which all the values are Going, Here is the insert page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script language="JavaScript" src="myminiAJAX.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="functions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
To Insert a new part<br/>
<form name="insert_values" action="insert.php" method="post">
    Select The Category<select name="combo_category" id="combo_category" onChange="doAjax('fill_combo_insertpart_combo_assembly.php', 'combo_category='+getValue('combo_category'), 'populate_combo_insertpart_combo_assembly', 'post', '1')">
    <option value="-1">--Please Select--</option>
    <option value="Brake">Brake</option>
    <option value="Fastner">Fastner</option>
    <option value="Suspension">Suspension</option>
    <option value="-1">--Please Select--</option>
    <option value="-1">--Please Select--</option>
    <option value="-1">--Please Select--</option>
    <option value="-1">--Please Select--</option>
    <option value="-1">--Please Select--</option>
    </select><br/><br/>
    Select The Assembly<select name="combo_assembly" id="combo_assembly" onchange="doAjax('fill_combo_index_and_indexpart_combo_part.php', 'par='+getValue('combo_assembly'), 'populate_combo_index_and_insertpart_part', 'post', '1')">
    <option value="-1">--Please Select--</option>
    </select><br/><br/>
    Select The Part:<select name="combo_part" id="combo_part">
    <option value="-1">--Please Select--</option>
    </select><br/><br/>
    Where Do you want to Insert?<br/><br/>
    Material<input type="radio" name="radio_insert_table" value="material" onclick="create_form_insertpart_material();doAjax('fill_combo_indexpart_combo_material.php','','populate_combo_insertpart_combo_material','post','1')"/>
    Process<input type="radio" name="radio_insert_table" value="process" onclick="create_form_insertpart_process();doAjax('fill_combo_indexpart_combo_process.php', '', 'populate_combo_insertpart_combo_process', 'post', '1');doAjax('fill_combo_indexpart_combo_multiplier.php', '','populate_combo_insertpart_combo_multiplier', 'post', '1')" />
    Fastner<input type="radio" name="radio_insert_table" value="fastner"/>

    <div id="form" ></div>
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="ipsubmit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In "`<div id="form">`" some new fields are created based on the radio button selection using javascript Here is the Code:

```
function create_form_insertpart_process() {
    document.getElementById("form").innerHTML="<select name=\"combo_process\" id=\"combo_process\" onChange=\"doAjax('fill_combo_indexpart_combo_process.php','process_name='+getValue('combo_process'),'populate_textbox_insertpart_process_unticost_and_unit','post','1')\"><option value=\"-1\">--Please Select--</option></select><br/><br/> ";
    document.getElementById("form").innerHTML+="<input type=\"text\" name=\"text_use\" id=\"text_use\" />";
    document.getElementById("form").innerHTML+="<input type=\"text\" name=\"text_unitcost\" id=\"text_unitcost\" disabled=\"disabled\" />";
    document.getElementById("form").innerHTML+="<input type=\"text\" name=\"text_unit\" id=\"text_unit\" disabled=\"disabled\" />";
    document.getElementById("form").innerHTML+="<input type=\"text\" name=\"text_quantity\" id=\"text_quantity\" />";
    document.getElementById("form").innerHTML+="<select name=\"combo_multiplier\" id=\"combo_multiplier\" onChange=\"doAjax('fill_combo_indexpart_combo_multiplier.php','multiplier_name='+getValue('combo_multiplier'),'populate_textbox_insertpart_multiplier_value','post','1')\"><option value=\"-1\">--Please Select--</option></select><br/><br/> ";
    document.getElementById("form").innerHTML+="<input type=\"text\" name=\"text_multipliervalue\" id=\"text_multipliervalue\" disabled=\"disabled\"/>";
    window.setInterval("calculate_textbox_insertpart_text_subtotal()",10);
    document.getElementById("form").innerHTML+="<input type=\"text\" name=\"text_subtotal\" id=\"text_subtotal\"  disabled=\"disabled\" />";

}
```

In The above code:

```
document.getElementById("form").innerHTML+="<input type=\"text\" name=\"text_unitcost\" id=\"text_unitcost\" disabled=\"disabled\" />";
```

The value of this fields is generated by a javascript function which returns the database from the server using AJAX and XML

and finally here is the page where I am writing a code to insert the value into database

```
<?php
    include("dbconfig.inc.php");
     $combo_category=$_POST['combo_category'];
     $combo_assembly=$_POST['combo_assembly'];
     $combo_part=$_POST['combo_part'];
     $radio_insert_table=$_POST['radio_insert_table'];
     if($radio_insert_table=="material") {

     }
     else if($radio_insert_table=="process") {
        $combo_process=$_POST['combo_process'];
        $text_use=$_POST['text_use'];
        $text_unitcost=$_POST['text_unitcost'];
        //$text_unit=$_POST['text_unit'];
        //$text_quantity=$_POST['text_quantity'];
        //$combo_multiplier=$_POST['combo_multiplier'];
        //$text_multipliervalue=$_POST['text_multipliervalue'];
        ////$text_subtotal=$_POST['text_subtotal'];
        $select=$dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO process (process_unitcost) values(:text_unitcost)');
        //$select->execute(array(':text_unitcost' => $text_unitcost));

     }
?>
```

In the above code i am getting an error in line 13 as undefined index text_unitcost

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you post INPUT fields that is disabled and has no value, they doesn't get posted, so therefore there is no index set for those.

Disabled fields doesn't get posted, You should use `readonly="readonly"` if you would want to show it but not allowing edits.

Reference http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12